# Is this the correct time complexity of my leetcode solution: merge k sorted linked lists into 1 sorted list?

Tags: typescript, algorithm, sorting, linked-list, time-complexity

The challenge:

```
You are given an array of k linked-lists lists, each linked-list is sorted in ascending order.
Merge all the linked-lists into one sorted linked-list and return it.
```

I'll put my code below, but briefly, my solution:

- Creates a sorted doubly-linked list containing a node for each list in the original array, where each node contains the value of the head node and the array index at which that node exists
- Pops off the head node of the singly-linked list at the index indicated by the head node of the doubly-linked list and attaches it to the tail of the result list
- Removes the head of the doubly-linked list and inserts a new node representing the new head of the list that was just popped
- Continues until the doubly-linked list is empty

I'm thinking this was actually not a very efficient way to do this. In the worst case, inserting a node into the doubly-linked list is O(k). I insert a new node into the list every time a node is popped off one of the singly-linked lists, so if n is the average length of each singly-linked list, wouldn't that make my overall time complexity O(k * (k*n)) = O(nk^2)? If so, I'm wondering how I didn't exceed the time limit with these constraints:

```
k == lists.length
0 <= k <= 10^4
0 <= lists[i].length <= 500
-10^4 <= lists[i][j] <= 10^4
```

Anyway here is my (Typescript) code with all the driver functions necessary to run:

```js
// nodes of the singly-linked lists given by the challenge
class ListNode {
    val: number
    next: ListNode | null
    constructor(val?: number, next?: ListNode | null) {
        this.val = (val === undefined ? 0 : val)
        this.next = (next === undefined ? null : next)
    }
}

// nodes for the doubly-linked list I used to keep track of what order
// in which to pop from the singly-linked lists
class OrderNode {
    headVal: number
    listIndex: number
    next: OrderNode | null
    prev: OrderNode | null
    constructor(val: number, i: number, next: OrderNode | null, prev: OrderNode | null) {
        this.headVal = val
        this.listIndex = i
        this.next = next === undefined ? null : next
        this.prev = prev === undefined ? null : prev
    }
}

// typescript bs
function nullFilter<TValue>(value: TValue | null | undefined): value is TValue {
    if (value === null || value === undefined) return false
    const test: TValue = value
    return true
}

// main function
function mergeKLists(lists: Array<ListNode | null>): ListNode | null {
    const filtered = lists.filter(nullFilter)
    if (!filtered.length) return null

    // create initial doubly-linked list
    let order: OrderNode = insert(null, filtered[0], 0)
    for (let i = 1; i < filtered.length; i++) {
        order = insert(order, filtered[i], i)
    }
    let remaining: OrderNode | null = order

    // set up initial variables for while loop
    const firstI = remaining.listIndex
    const firstNode = filtered[firstI]
    let head: ListNode | null = push(null, firstNode)
    let tail: ListNode | null = head
    const firstInsert = shiftList(filtered, firstI)
    remaining = shiftOrder(remaining)
    if (firstInsert) {
        remaining = insert(remaining, firstInsert, firstI)
    }
    // main while loop
    while (remaining) {
        const i = remaining.listIndex
        // get node to push to end of result list
        const pushNode = filtered[i]
        // shift that node and get the new head
        const newHead = shiftList(filtered, i)
        // shift the head of the order list
        remaining = shiftOrder(remaining)
        // if there are nodes left in the popped list, add the new head to the order list
        if (newHead) {
            remaining = insert(remaining, newHead, i)
        }
        tail = push(tail, pushNode)
    }
    return head
}

// push a node to the end of the result list
function push(tail: ListNode | null, node: ListNode): ListNode {
    const newNode = new ListNode(node.val, null)
    if (tail) {
        tail.next = newNode
    }
    return newNode
}

// insert a new node into the sorted list keeping track of order
function insert(head: OrderNode | null, node: ListNode, i: number): OrderNode {
    const newNode = new OrderNode(node.val, i, null, null)
    if (!head) {
        return newNode
    } else {
        if (node.val <= head.headVal) {
            head.prev = newNode
            newNode.next = head
            return newNode
        } else {
            let temp: OrderNode | null = head
            let prev: OrderNode | null = null
            while (temp) {
                if (temp.headVal >= node.val) break
                prev = temp
                temp = temp.next
            }
            prev = prev as OrderNode
            if (temp) {
                prev.next = newNode
                newNode.prev = prev
                newNode.next = temp
                temp.prev = newNode
                return head
            } else {
                prev.next = newNode
                newNode.prev = prev
                return head
            }
        }
    }
}

// shift the head from the order list
function shiftOrder(head: OrderNode | null): OrderNode | null {
    if (head) {
        if (head.next) {
            const newHead = head.next
            newHead.prev = null
            return newHead
        } else {
            return null
        }
    } else {
        return null
    }
}

// shift a node from one of the given lists, and return the new head
function shiftList(lists: Array<ListNode | null>, i: number): ListNode | null {
    let currentHead = lists[i]
    if (currentHead) {
        lists[i] = currentHead.next
        return lists[i]
    } else {
        return null
    }
}

// driver code
const input: number[][] = [
    [1, 4, 5],
    [1, 3, 4],
    [2, 6],
]
const lists = input.map(array => {
    let next = null
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        next = new ListNode(array[i], next)
    }
    return next
})

let result = mergeKLists(lists)
while (result) {
    process.stdout.write(`${result.val} -> `)
    result = result.next
}
```

Comment: That looks super complicated. If I'm understanding the problem, I'd flatten all the values into an object, then just iterate over the object in ascending key order to create the new list. Or you could iterate over all the lists in parallel and create the new list all at once.

Comment: @CertainPerformance how would you iterate in parallel? I kind of thought that's what I'm doing, I'm just using that extra list to keep track of which list's head has the next lowest value. I guess iterating through the array each time to find the next lowest value is probably the same time complexity as what I did?

Comment: Without going into the list implementation, for a standard array of arrays, keep an index for each array being iterated over, of the next element to pick from the array. Iterate through all subarrays once, identify the smallest element(s), extract them, and update each of those indicies. Repeat to the end. I'd be pretty simple. Same sort of approach would work for the linked list, except you'd have to account for its strange data structure.

Comment: @CertainPerformance too funny - I simply pushed every value from each list into a single array, sorted the array, and made a new linked list from the sorted array - faster than 96% of all typescript submissions. You were right about flattening haha

Comment: `how would you iterate in parallel?` - using pairwise merge, with T threads, T pairs of lists at a time could be merged in parallel. This would be repeated until all K lists were merged into K/2 lists. The next iteration would result in K/4 lists. Eventually there will be fewer than T pairs of lists, in which case fewer threads would be used, and finally the last pair of lists are merged to form the single merged list using a single thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two "computer science" ways of doing it:

- Use a heap instead of a doubly linked list, which allows you to pop (and re-insert<sup>1</sup>) the list that has the least value in its head node.

  ---

  <sub><sup>1</sup> If the heap implementation provides a replace (exchange) method, then use that instead of a separate pop & push action.</sub>
- Merge lists pairwise, so the number of lists reduces (while their size increases), until only one list remains. To make this efficient, this should be done by a divide-and-conquer algorithm (recursion), each time solving the merge by splitting the lists array in halves, until there is only one list left as base case. Then -- while backtracking -- perform the merge on the two lists that come back from recursion.

I will here demo the second solution in a runnable JavaScript snippet:

```js
class ListNode {
    constructor(val, next=null) {
        this.val = val;
        this.next = next;
    }
}

// main function
function mergeKLists(lists) {
    // Divide and conquer
    if (lists.length < 2) return lists[0]; // Base case
    const i = lists.length >> 1; // Half
    const pair = [mergeKLists(lists.slice(0, i)), mergeKLists(lists.slice(i))];
    // Merge pair of non-empty lists:
    const head = popLeast(pair);
    let tail = head;
    while (pair[0] && pair[1]) {
        tail = tail.next = popLeast(pair);
    }
    tail.next = pair[0] ?? pair[1]; // Attach the remainder
    return head;
}

function popLeast(pair) {
    const i = pair[0].val < pair[1].val ? 0 : 1;
    const least = pair[i];
    pair[i] = least.next;
    return least;
}

// Helper functions for I/O
function stringify(head) {
    const nodes = [];
    while (head) {
        nodes.push(head.val);
        head = head.next;
    }
    return nodes.join(" -> ");
}

function createList(values) {
    let head = null;
    for (const val of values.reverse()) {
        head = new ListNode(val, head);
    }
    return head;
}

// driver code
const lists = [
    [1, 4, 5],
    [1, 3, 4],
    [2, 6],
].map(createList);

const result = mergeKLists(lists);

console.log(stringify(result));
```

This has a better time complexity than the solution with the doubly linked list: it is O(nklogk) instead of O(nk²).

It should be mentioned that JavaScript is quite fast when you convert everything to an array and perform a sort on that. But this kind of exercises is intended to be solved with a minimum use of space (excluding the part where you need to create or print the lists)

Comment: What would the time complexity be fro the first way?

Comment: Also O(nklogk).

Comment: time-complex `O(N*logK)`.

N is the total number of nodes. 
k is the number of linked lists.

Found at https://leetcode.ca/2015-12-23-23-Merge-k-Sorted-Lists/#big-o-analysis

Comment: Yes, @keypoint, that's the same thing, but with a different definition of n.

Comment: In my answer,  the array pairwise version is faster than the heap version. The main difference is with heap version, every node merged involves a heap sift O(log(k)), while the array version avoids this Using C++ versions of the code below, with 16384 lists with 1024 nodes each, array version is ~2.0 times as fast, and with 1MB (1024*1024) lists with 16 nodes each, array version is ~2.6 times as fast.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript code examples for heap version and a non-recursive pairwise merge version, using a small array (small array version is faster). With the same code in C++, 1024 lists with 16384 nodes each, on my system, heap version takes 3.6 seconds, while array version is twice as fast at 1.8 seconds.

```js
class ListNode {
    constructor(val, next=null) {
        this.val = val;
        this.next = next;
    }
}

function mergeKLists(lists) {
    var k = lists.length;
    heap(lists);                        // convert to min heap
    const head = lists[0];              // merged list = list[0]
    var tail = head;
    while (true) {
        lists[0] = lists[0].next;       // lists[0] = next node
        if (lists[0] == null) {         // if end of lists[0]
            if(--k == 0)                //  reduce heap size
                break;
            lists[0] = lists[k];        //  lists[0] = last list
        }
        sift(lists, 0, k);              // fix heap
        tail = tail.next = lists[0];    // append node to merged list
    }
    return head;
}

function heap(lists) {                  // convert lists to min heap
    var i = (lists.length-1)/2;
    while (i >= 0) {
        sift(lists, i, lists.length);
        i--;
    }
}

function sift(lists, i, k) {            // sift lists[i] down 
    var m = i;
    while (true) {
        i = m;
        var l = 2*i+1;
        var r = 2*i+2;
        if(l < k && lists[l].val < lists[i].val)
            m = l;
        if(r < k && lists[r].val < lists[m].val)
            m = r;
        if(m == i)
            break;
        [lists[i], lists[m]] = [lists[m], lists[i]];
    }
}

function stringify(head) {
    const nodes = [];
    while (head) {
        nodes.push(head.val);
        head = head.next;
    }
    return nodes.join(" -> ");
}

function createList(values) {
    let head = null;
    for (var val of values.reverse()) {
        head = new ListNode(val, head);
    }
    return head;
}

const lists = [
    [1, 4, 5],
    [1, 3, 4],
    [2, 6],
].map(createList);

const result = mergeKLists(lists);

console.log(stringify(result));
```

Non-recursive pairwise merge version, using a small array ar[] instead of the stack, where ar[i] == null or ar[i] = 2^i merged lists (ar[0] used to hold a single list). A bottom up merge sort approach for the array of lists could also be used, but a naive version would need a second array with size K, while in this version, the second array size is ceil(log2(K+1)).

```js
class ListNode {
    constructor(val, next=null) {
        this.val = val;
        this.next = next;
    }
}

function mergeKLists(lists) {
    if (lists.length < 2) return lists[0];
    const sz = Math.ceil(Math.log2(lists.length+1));
    const ar = new Array(sz).fill(null);
    var   mg = null;
    var i, j;
    for (j = 0; j < lists.length; j++) {
        // merge lists[j] into ar[]
        mg = lists[j];
        for (i = 0; ar[i] != null; i++) {
            mg = merge(ar[i], mg);
            ar[i] = null;
        }
        ar[i] = mg;
    }
    // merge ar[] into single list
    for (i = 0; ar[i] == null; i++);
    mg = ar[i];
    for (++i ; i < sz; i++)
        if (ar[i] != null)
            mg = merge(ar[i], mg);
    return mg;
}

function merge(l0, l1) {
    var pair = [l0, l1];
    var head = popLeast(pair);
    var tail = head;
    while (pair[0] && pair[1])
        tail = tail.next = popLeast(pair);
    tail.next = pair[0] ?? pair[1];
    return head;
}

function popLeast(pair) {
    const i = pair[0].val < pair[1].val ? 0 : 1;
    const least = pair[i];
    pair[i] = least.next;
    return least;
}

function stringify(head) {
    const nodes = [];
    while (head) {
        nodes.push(head.val);
        head = head.next;
    }
    return nodes.join(" -> ");
}

function createList(values) {
    let head = null;
    for (const val of values.reverse()) {
        head = new ListNode(val, head);
    }
    return head;
}

const lists = [
    [1, 4, 5],
    [1, 3, 4],
    [2, 6],
].map(createList);

const result = mergeKLists(lists);

console.log(stringify(result));
```